# Django login app at suburl, url redirection does not work properly

Tags: python, django, apache

I have my page deployed at `http://example.com`. I also have my django application deployed at `http://example.com/djangoapp`.

I'm using `Apache 2.2` with this configuration (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`): `WSGIPythonPath /home/brian/djangoprojects/djangoapp`.

I also added the line `WSGIScriptAlias /djangoapp /home/brian/djangoprojects/djangoapp/djangoapp/wsgi.py` to the default `Apache Virtual Host` file and it works really nice.

However, in my application I'm using the `auth` module to register and login users, and have some problems with it. Sometimes I got redirected to the main page, `http://example.com/`, sometimes to `http://example.com/register` instead of `http://example.com/djangoapp/register`.

Changes I made in my project:

1. Edited `settings.py` and added:

> ```
> LOGIN_URL = '/djangoapp/accounts/login/'
> USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
> FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/djangoapp'
> SUB_SITE = "/djangoapp"
> ```

2. My `urls.py` file looks like this:

> ```
> from django.conf.urls import include, url
> from django.contrib import admin
> from djangoapp import views
>
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
>     url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
>     url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_page),
>     url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),  # If user is not login it will redirect to login page
>     url(r'^register/$', views.register),
>     url(r'^register/success/$', views.register_success),
>     url(r'^home/$', views.home),
> ]
> ```

3. And here's my `views.py` file:

> ```
> from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
> from django.contrib.auth import logout
> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
> from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
> from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
> from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
> from django.template import RequestContext
> from djangoapp.forms import RegistrationForm
>
>
> @csrf_protect
> def register(request):
>     if request.method == 'POST':
>         form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
>         if form.is_valid():
>             user = User.objects.create_user(
>                 username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
>                 password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
>                 email=form.cleaned_data['email']
>             )
>             return HttpResponseRedirect('register/success/')
>     else:
>         form = RegistrationForm()
>     variables = RequestContext(request, {
>         'form': form
>     })
>
>     return render_to_response(
>         'registration/register.html',
>         variables,
>     )
>
>
> def register_success(request):
>     return render_to_response(
>         'registration/success.html',
>     )
>
>
> def logout_page(request):
>     logout(request)
>     return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
>
>
> @login_required
> def home(request):
>     return render_to_response(
>         'home.html',
>         {'user': request.user}
>     )
> ```

This is the production server and it's available online. I tried to use a work-around, but with no effect. I simply changed links on page and added `djangoapp` at the beginning, for instance:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block head %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
        <table border="0">
            <tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td>{{ form.username }}</td></tr>
            <tr><th><label for="id_password">Password:</label></th><td>{{ form.password }}</td></tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/home" />
    </form>
    <a href="register">Register</a>
{% endblock %}
```

And I tried to change `<a href="register">Register</a>` to `<a href="djangoapp/register">Register</a>` but I'm sure there's got to be a smarter solution. Any advice?

Comment: A solution to what? You haven't said what's not working. FYI, there should be no need to use FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME at all: as long as you use the `url` tag everywhere, your links will just work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I said what's not working, maybe it wasn't clear, if so, I'm sorry. When I'm on a main page the (which is also a login page: `http://example.com/djangoapp`), and click register, it redirects me to `http://example.com/register` instead of `http://example.com/djangoapp/register` and there is the same error with other pages as well. Here's my main (login page): http://pastie.org/private/yxokiwsnxubvjlv4tn6qog which is in path: `/home/brian/djangoprojects/djangoapp/templates/registration/login.html`
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `{% url %}` tag and the `reverse` function consistently. So:

```
<a href="{% url "register" %}">Register</a>
```

and

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('register_success'))
```

For this to work you also need to give your URL patterns names:

```
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name="register"),
url(r'^register/success/$', views.register_success, name="register_success"),
```

Aso, as I said in the comment, you do not need to set FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Should I do the analogic changes to remaining urls, views and hrefs?

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work now. However, I have the last question, if you don't mind. How can I change the `def home(request):` function to work, so I can have the username on home page? Now it only displays an empty string. Here's my edited `views.py` file: http://pastie.org/private/yow4rodw2r34xdvnwcx58g and `urls.py` file: http://pastie.org/private/uvmxys4fmmhjpx1hxkbaug. Btw, is there any good tutorial which will explain all this? I'm learing Django right now. Many, many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be related to this problem at all. Please ask a new question, and include your view and template there.